# Does TYPO3 officially support MySQL / Maria DB strict modes (e.g. strict_trans_tables, innodb_strict_mode) etc

Tags: sql, typo3

Since MariaDB 10.2.4 defaults is:

```
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

and

```
innodb_strict_mode = ON
```

System requirements on https://get.typo3.org and in Installation guide do not explicitly mention it, but I know the restriction about not supporting strict mode got removed from the readme quite some time ago. I am not sure about innodb_strict_mode though.

Is there anything else to consider? What about third party extensions?

---

Resources:

---

Since MariaDB 10.2.4 defaults is:

```
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/

> When this manual refers to “strict mode,” it means a mode with either or both STRICT_TRANS_TABLES or STRICT_ALL_TABLES enabled.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html

Since MariaDB 10.2.2

```
innodb_strict_mode = ON
```

> InnoDB strict mode is similar to SQL strict mode. When it is enabled, certain InnoDB warnings become errors instead.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-strict-mode/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't intended as a full answer, but too long for a comment.

Had a lot of 3rd party EXT going haywire. It is often manageable if you install the extension anew, but upgrading an old install into an STRICT db resulted e.g. in just some views/subpages throwing exceptions while the rest of the system seemed to work. 
You might spot a problematic extension due to the SQL definition making problems already (e.g. wrong default values), but that isn't a guarantee.
However sometimes specific queries cause problems as mentioned above. Most of the times however it is hacky SQL or using implicit type casts (especially date fields).

Checking an extension if its sql file would work and if it is using Doctrine throughout is a good indicator IMHO. But even for the rest nothing an acceptance regression test suite can't find, but some of the errors were such a PITA we disabled STRICT mode again.

Nevertheless: there is no reason not all extensions should allow strict mode.